# Startup error on neovim 'has_package' attempts to call a nil value

Tags: neovim, packer, mason

I am trying to use [these](https://github.com/josean-dev/dev-environment-files/tree/packer-nvim-setup/.config/nvim) configurations for neovim, but every time I start the editor I get:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...ason-null-ls.nvim/lua/mason-null-ls/ensure_installed.lua:11: attempt to call field 'has_package' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...ason-null-ls.nvim/lua/mason-null-ls/ensure_installed.lua:11: in function 'mapper_fn'
        ...pack/packer/start/mason.nvim/lua/mason-core/optional.lua:34: in function 'resolve_package'
        ...ason-null-ls.nvim/lua/mason-null-ls/ensure_installed.lua:26: in function <...ason-null-ls.nvim/lua/mason-null-ls/ensure_installed.lua:21>
        ...cker/start/mason-null-ls.nvim/lua/mason-null-ls/init.lua:88: in function 'setup'
        /home/user/.config/nvim/lua/jesme/plugins/lsp/mason.lua:42: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:10: in main chunk
Error in packer_compiled: vim/_editor.lua:0: /home/user/.config/nvim/plugin/packer_compiled.lua..nvim_exec2() called at /home/user/.config/nvim/plugin/packer_compiled.lua:0../home/user/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer
/start/nvim-treesitter/plugin/nvim-treesitter.lua: Vim(packadd):E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:533: Overriding has-ancestor?^@stack traceback:^@^I[C]: in function 'erro
r'^@^I/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:533: in function 'add_predicate'^@^I...nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/query_predicates.lua:64: in main chunk^@^I[C]: in function 'require'^@^I...ack/packer/start/nv
im-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter.lua:8: in main chunk^@^I[C]: in function 'require'^@^I.../packer/start/nvim-treesitter/plugin/nvim-treesitter.lua:9: in main chunk^@^I[C]: in function 'nvim_exec2'^@^Ivim/_editor.lua: in functio
n 'cmd'^@^I/home/user/.config/nvim/plugin/packer_compiled.lua:244: in function </home/user/.config/nvim/plugin/packer_compiled.lua:10>^@^I[C]: in function 'pcall'^@^I/home/user/.config/nvim/plugin/packer_compiled.lua:10
: in main chunk
Please check your config for correctness
```

What is the cause of these errors and how can I fix them?